# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1

Tags: java

I have the most curious index problem I could imagine. I have the following innocent-looking code:

```
int lastIndex = givenOrder.size() - 1;
if (lastIndex >= 0 && givenOrder.get(lastIndex).equals(otherOrder)) {
    givenOrder.remove(lastIndex);
}
```

Looks like a proper pre-check to me. (The list here is declared as `List`, so there is no direct access to the last element, but that is immaterial for the question anyway.) I get the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:445) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at my.code.Here:48) ~[Here.class:na]
```

At runtime, it’s a simple `ArrayList`. Now, index 0 should be quite inside the bounds!

---

### Edit

Many people have suggested that introducing synchronization would solve the problem. I do not doubt it. But the core of my (admittedly unexpressed) question is different: How is that behaviour even possible?

Let me elaborate. We have 5 steps here:

1. I check the size and compute `lastIndex` (size is 1 here)
2. I even access that last element
3. I request removal
4. `ArrayList` checks the bounds, finding them inadequate
5. `ArrayList` constructs the exception message and throws

Strictly speaking, granularity could be even finer. Now, 50,000 times it works as expected, no concurrency issues. (Frankly, I haven’t even found any other place where that list could be modified, but the code is too large to rule that out.)

Then, one time it breaks. That’s normal for concurrency issues. However, it breaks in an entirely unexpected way. Somewhere after step 2 and before step 4, the list is emptied. I would expect an exception saying `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`, which is bad enough. But I never saw an exception like this in the last months!

Instead, I see `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1` which means that after step 4 but before step 5 the list gains one element. While this is possible, it seems about as unlikely as the phenomenon above. Yet, it happens each time that the error occurs! As a mathematician, I say that this is just very unprobable. But my common sense tells me that there is another issue.

Moreover, looking at the code in `ArrayList`, you see very short functions there that are run hundreds of times, and no volatile variable anywhere. That means that I would very much expect the hotspot compiler to have elided the function calls, making the critical section much smaller; and the elided the double access to the `size` variable, making the observed behaviour impossible. Clearly, this isn’t happening.

So, my question is why this can happen at all and why it happens in this weird way. Suggesting synchronization is not an answer to the question (it may be a solution to the problem, but that is a different matter).

Comment: Share the `List`, please.

Comment: Add an element before you check as proof to yourself the ArrayList really was empty.

Comment: Another process or thread is modifying the ArrayList.

Comment: I think u are using this in a loop and this loop turn one more than you think. Show us your loop.

Comment: I admit this is interesting case. You have no problems with reproducing that? It looks like bug in JDK  - rather minor like missleading exception message. Please POINT THE LINE THAT THROWS EXCEPTION. Any concurrent modification to your collection? If so, share its code as well.

Comment: @CodeCamper: The list is not empty. Not when I check, not when it checks itself.

Comment: @hurricane: You think so, but that’s not the case; no loop is involved.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel if you are so sure the list is not empty why don't you try adding an element to the list you are checking just to prove it to yourself.

Comment: @Antoniossss No, it is almost unreproducible. It shows in our logs about once a week and works about 50,000 times in the meantime. I do not know who else might modify that list (large code-base), but that is probably the cause. However, looking at `ArrayList.java` it seems impossible that this exception be thrown while `index < size`. The list seems to have size 1 when I check myself, size 0 when `ArrayList` checks, and then size 1 again when the error message is produced.

Comment: You will have to introduce `synchronized` version of this list or at least synchronize code you have posted.  This is a concurrent issue that reveals some sort of bug in `ArrayList` internals

Answer (score 4):

So I have checked the source code for `ArrayList` implementation of `rangeCheck` - method that throws exception and this is what I have found:

```
private void rangeCheck(int paramInt) //given index
{
    if (paramInt < this.size) // compare param with list size
        return;
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(paramInt)); // here we have exception
}
```

and relevant `outOfBoundsMsg` method

```
private String outOfBoundsMsg(int paramInt)
{
    return "Index: " + paramInt + ", Size: " + this.size; /// OOOoo we are reading size again!
}
```

So as you can probably see, size (`this.size`) of list is accessed 2 times. First time it is read to check condition and the condition is not fullfilled, so the message is build for the exception. While creating message for the exception, only `paramInt` is persistent between calls, but size of list is read second time. And here we have our culprit.

In real, you should get Message : `Index:0 Size:0`, but the size value used for checking is not locally stored (microoptimalization). So between these 2 reads of `this.size` list has been changed.

That is why message is missleading.

Conclussion:
Such situation is possible in hightly concurrent environement, and can be very hard to reproduce. To solve that problem use `synchronized` version of `ArrayList` (like @JordiCastillia suggested). This solution can have impact on performance as every operation (add/remove and probably get) will be `synchronized`. Other solution would be to put your code into `synchronized` block, but this will only synchronized your calls in this piece of code, and the problem can still occure in the future, as different parts of the system can still access whole object async.

Comment: The fun fact is that in order for that to happen, the list must be modified _twice_: Once after my own `get()` call that succeeds, and once again after the check in `rangeCheck()`. That is unlikely, but of course possible. However, I _never_ get this exception with a meaningful message. That means, whenever the list is modified after the `get()`, it is also modified after the check in `rangeCheck()`. Now this is simply too unlikely to believe in a coincidence. Moreover, since `size` is not `volatile` and we are looking at tiny private functiont, shouldn’t the JIT compiler have inlined it?

Comment: I guess that is the (one of) the reason that `ArrayList` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a concurrency issue.

The size gets *somehow* modified before/after you tried to access the index.

Comment: _Most likely_ and _somehow_ do not answer the question. It quite probably is a concurrency issue somewhere, but how can `rangeCheck` in `ArrayList.java:604` throw when `index < size`?

Comment: If you want a precise answer, post your real code. We have to guess what is going on here. Also, I took some time to understand your problem and write an answer, which probably does not deserve a downvote

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)).

Tested in a simple `main` it works:

```
List<String> givenOrder = new ArrayList<>();
String otherOrder = "null";
givenOrder.add(otherOrder);

int lastIndex = givenOrder.size() - 1;
if (lastIndex >= 0 && givenOrder.get(lastIndex).equals(otherOrder)) {
   System.out.println("remove");
   givenOrder.remove(lastIndex);
}
```

Are you on a `thread-safe` process? Your `List` is modified by some other thread or process.

Comment: That exception makes sense with @JordiCastilla answer, another thread can be modifying the list after lastIndex is assigned

Comment: @Antoniossss the size and the error are not in same line, so if a different thread modifies the `List` this info wont be correct when object in the List is being removed

Comment: @GuillermoMerino i simply don't get it, `lastIndex` is irrelevant to me with that exception.

Comment: @GuillermoMerino in my opinion this is most probable concurrent issue, but the exception here is more than missleading as given index is in bounds.

Comment: Unfortunately, your simple test is too simple, as this works almost always.

Comment: no almost, code you posted works **ALWAYS**... I posted to proof your code is ok by itself and you have a **concurrency issue not related with  code you posted**... use `Collections.synchronizedList()` or make this piece of code `thread-safe` with `synchronice` and you will get expected result.

Comment: @JordiCastilla I did not mean _your_ almost always works, I know it always does, I meant _my_ code almost always works (even in a distributed environment), and that isolating it removes the source of the problem. I also firmly believe that synchronisation will make the error disappear, but unfortunately that leaves the question unanswered.

Comment: If synchronzing the list solves the problem you have the answer... problem is Concurrency for sure... But now, we need full scenario to reproduce your issue, if no we cannot answer the question itself but the problem.